How can a Flink Job automatically resume from a Checkpoint on a Redeploy
I'm hosting flink jobs on an EKS cluster and using Kubectl to create/update/delete flink jobs with a flink_deployment.yaml file.
We have checkpoints and HA stored in a remote AWS EFS storage which is mounted to on the flink job local directory in some path called /flink_checkpoints. I've noticed that the checkpoints are stored in folders with the jobId. However the jobId doesn't look like something that you can manually specify.
On a redeploy of the flink job. I.e. when we delete the flink job with kubectl delete and create it again using kubectl create the flink job is redeployed with a new jobId and hence does not resume from the previous checkpoint.
If we were to update the flink job with kubectl apply this does resume from the checkpoint since the jobId remains the same. Even though the job managers and task managers are deleted.
Does anyone know of a way that we can resume from the checkpoint on a redeploy (delete and create)? Using the checkpoint much like a savepoint seem like a possible solution, however all the checkpoints are stored under a folder named after the jobId and if a cluster goes down with lets say 50 jobs then how do we even begin to map the random jobIds to the job name?
I'm not sure if there is some setting I'm missing with the flink_deployment.yaml file which might be able to turn this on. Or if this is not something that flink supports - This seems strange as what happens in the case of a cluster suddenly going down and all the flink jobs are lost?
n.b. I noticed that we also have a folder for High availability and this folder does contain folders created with the job names. Not sure how this is related or somehow relevant.

I've tried running an update with kubectl apply and this does indeed resume from the checkpoint and state is saved.
Running kuebctl delete followed by kuebctl create to redeploy the flink job has not been successful since a new job ID is submitted.
